# Configure angularjs app in tomcat with multiple views

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, web-applications, angularjs-routing, angularjs-view

I configured a small angular app in tomcat its working fine, but when i tried to use route-Provider its not working.
I cannot route to my views.
I did not know why ?

Can any one give some small example for that.

My Code files

```
//this is controllers.js
var myapp = angular.module('sampleapp', []);
myapp.config('$routeProvider',function myRoute($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/admin.html',
        controller: 'adminController'
      })
      when('/showdata', {
          templateUrl: 'partials/data-view.html',
          controller: 'dataController'
        }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });


adminController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Welcome to Login Page";
}

dataController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Welcome to Show Data Page";
}

myapp.controller(controllers)
```

my index.html

```
<html>
<base href="/advangularjs/" />
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="demoweb_angular/controllers.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="sampleapp" style="background-color: #E0EEE0">

<a href="#"> Login </a> |
<a href="showdata"> Show Data </a>

<div ng-view align="center" style="border: 1px solid red;">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

admin.html

```
<b>{{ message }}</b>
```

data-view.html

```
<b>{{ message }}</b>
```

Comment: any codes u have tried ?

Comment: yes i had tried a very simple example but still I cant find it working

Comment: please post the code u have tried.

Comment: I posted my code can you please have a sight on it for any corrections

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added angular-route.js
in your index.html file.

Also Please go through the documentation of ui router for the basic setup

Comment: I had posted my code can you please find problems in it, if any

Comment: Still i am finding solution for this question, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myapp = angular.module('sampleapp', ['ngRoute']);
```

u need to add `ngRoute` dependancy also. Because your `sampleapp` is depend on `ngRoute` .

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

you need to add this also. the partial are loading to this div. put this inside the `body`.

Comment: its one and the same thing what i did and you are trying to say
the last update is not useful at all.

Comment: Still i am finding solution for this question, can you help me ?

Comment: can you please create a plunker demo

Comment: its working in plunker but not when i configure that in apache tomcat as a web application

Comment: are you using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` ?

Comment: nope i dint use html5Mode but any ways thanks for helping me to solve this issue. I found the solution, you answers were relevant but i was having some different issue.